# For Loops Code Optimization

Tags: java, optimization, loops

I had a challenge to print out multiples of 7 (non-negative) to the 50th multiple in the simplest way humanly possible using for loops.

I came up with this (Ignoring the data types)

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 350; i += 7)
         {System.out.println(i);}
```

The other guy came up with this

```
for(int i=0;i <=50; i++)
{
System.out.println(7*i);
}
```

However, I feel the two code snippets could be further optimized. If it actually can please tell. And what are the advantages/disadvantages of one over the other?

Comment: You want to optimize this? The output part will take roughly 99.99% of the time, with the actual math taking way too little time to even spend a single thought on whether to optimize it, much less how. By the time you arrive at enlightenment and realize all that and even more reasons you shouldn't worry,, you've already spent countless times the time it takes to make these calculations thousands and thousands of times. Way to waste time ;)

Comment: there's for(int i=0; i<1; i++) System.out.println("0,7,...."); // :-)

Comment: The fastest execution would be to unroll the loops and just print each number: `System.out.println("0"); System.out.println("7"); System.out.println("14"); ...` . But you ruled that out in the premise to the challenge. :-P However, "the simplest way humanly possible" can mean many different things; I would it to mean "easiest to maintain" and/or "easiest to understand what's going on by looking at the code," not "fastest."

Comment: @delnan: I with I could find the comment where I first heard the expression "getting a haircut to lose weight".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one technically performs less operations (no multiplication).

The second one is slightly more readable (50 multiples of 7 vs. multiples of 7 up to 350).

Probably can't be optimized any further.

Unless you're willing to optimize away multiple `println` calls by doing:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i <= 350; i += 7) s.append(i).append(", ");

System.out.println(s.toString());
```

(IIRC `println`s are relatively expensive.)

This is getting to the point where you gain a tiny bit of optimization at the expense of simplicity.

Comment: But `i++` is faster than `i+7`.

Comment: @fastcodejava: Says who? And even if, could you measure a difference even for insanely many iterations?

Comment: @fastcodejava - How do you know that `i++` is always faster than `i+7`?

Comment: There is no need for this, seriously.

Comment: But CPU's multiplication is basically addition??

Comment: @fastcodejava: doing `i++` and then `i*7` is almost certainly more expensive than just doing `i+=7`.

Comment: @Mobinga no it's not. The second code is more readable. The first code makes an assignment in which php casts integer value on a string each time behind the scenes.

Comment: @trutheality my bad, it doesn't matter, Java runtime makes the casting

Comment: @Tom: You still cast either way though. Sort of unavoidable when you need to print integers.

Comment: @trutheality That's not true. In Java you have core integer, float etc variables and strings are a wrapper class of it's own. So when you print integers it doesn't go through that ecosystem

Comment: @Tom: `println(int x)` still calls `String.valueOf(int x)` which calls `Integer.toString(int x)`.

Comment: @trutheality I didn't say whole lot faster, only a tiny bit faster.

Comment: @trutheality That's just not true. Multiplication and division are slower than an addition. As a matter of fact for the normal arithmetic instructions mul has a 3times lower reciprocal throughput than add in the best case.

Comment: @Voo: do you have a reference on that?

Comment: @trutheality Sure, [this here](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) - reciprocal throughput for SB on an add r, r is 0.33; imul r,r has 1. Or otherwise said you can get 3 independent adds for the cost of one mul (and then just look at how much more expensive a single division is compared to the rest)

Comment: @Voo: thanks for the link! Don't know why I thought I remembered one ALU operation always taking the same number of cycles regardless of what it is.

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to optimize it, do this:

```
System.out.print("0\n7\n14\n21\n28\n35\n42\n49\n56\n63\n70\n77\n84\n91\n98\n105\n112\n119\n126\n133\n140\n147\n154\n161\n168\n175\n182\n189\n196\n203\n210\n217\n224\n231\n238\n245\n252\n259\n266\n273\n280\n287\n294\n301\n308\n315\n322\n329\n336\n343\n350");
```

and it's `O(1)` :)

Comment: ++ Even faster would be to have the results in a file, and just `cat` it.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, your code is faster since it does not need one less multiplication instruction per loop.

However, the multiple calls to `System.out.println` (and the integer-to-string conversion) will **dwarf** the runtime the multiplication takes. To optimize, aggregate the Strings with a [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and output the whole result (or output the result when memory becomes a problem).

However, in real-world code, this is *extremely* unlikely to be the bottleneck. **Profile, then optimize**.

Answer (score 0):

The second function is the best you would get:
O(n)

Comment: @Both functions are `O(n)`, and the constant of the asymptotic complexities is actually meaningful here.

Comment: First function is not `O(n)`?

Comment: I know they are both O(n) the second one makes fewer iterations thus more optimized. And when scaling even greater optimized

Comment: Both make exactly the same number of iterations, only with different step sizes.